# Redirecting user to oauth2 authorization server to get token Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have 2 apps running, one is resource server where I have the info that needs authentication to view the text. Then I have authorization server that gives tokens. Right now I can use postman or Insomnia, add the auth_url, token_url, client_id, client_secret and I get the token. I add the token to header and i get do a get request to my resource server using header, and it works just fine.

Now i have no idea how to implement redirection from my resource server directly. Like when I go to

> localhost:9000/home

I'd like to get redirected to:

> localhost:9001/login

where I login with my inmemory  user then it redirects me back to localhost:9000/home and I see the message.

What would be the best way to implement a way for user to access information on localhost:9000/home. You go to localhost:9000/home, it goes to authorization server on localhost:9001, you log in with username and password. Approve the grant, and it puts you back to localhost:9000/home and then you can see the text, what was previously protected, because you didn't have token to access it.

ResourceServer.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class SampleResourceApplication extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**").hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleResourceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "this is home";
    }

}
```

and my properties looks like:

```
server:
  port: 900
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: foo
      client-secret: foosecret
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:9001/auth/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:9001/auth/oauth/authorize
      grant-type: USER
      auto-approve-scopes: true
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9001/auth/user
```

Comment: It is not really part of the `OAuth2` specification. Normally, you sohuld return a 401 when someone access to your RS without providing a token. It's not your RS job to redirect to the AS

Comment: @Nathan but what would be the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: When you reach `localhost:9000/home`, you simply get a 401 (you can send some detail in the body if you want). Your client should know where he has to get the token, and how he should get it. You can specify in your error body the cause: "Missing token", "Expired token", "Insufficienht scopes", ...

Comment: @Nathan yea i understand that, i was more thinking of how to implement the user login functions, so user can see to content on localhost:9000/home withouth actualy using something like postman or insomnia

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking now. Can you update your question so everyone can see this? This will be more clear :p

Comment: @Nathan alright, I tried to be more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's separate the agents: You have the **user** (i.e. you, also know as the **resource owner**), the **authorization server**, the **resource server** and the **client** (the application that access your urls, i.e. your browser).

Normally, this happens in your situation:

1. When your **client** access the **resource server**, it receives a `401`. Depending of your implementation, you could also directly redirect the **client** to your **AS** (using a simple redirect response).
2. Your **AS** prompts you for credentials. After validating them, it issues a token for you. You can then use this token to access the **RS**.

What you're trying to get (if I understand correctly) is to redirect with the token automatically. To achieve this, you can simply pass the url you tried to reach (i.e. `localhost:9000/home`) when you redirect to your **AS** at the end of step 1. Your **AS** hten prompts the user for credentials, generate the token, stores it as a cookie (in the case of a browser), and redirects you to the url he received (`localhost:9000/home`).

**EDIT: what's the resulting code for the redirection.**

When you get to the `configure`, you first check if the user is authenticated. If he is, then all's fine, but if he isn't, you must catch this event and start your redirection. This can be done using the `exceptionHandling` method of the chaining `http`:

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**").hasRole("user")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
}

private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    return new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        // You can use a lambda here
        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest aRequest, HttpServletResponse aResponse,
               AuthenticationException aAuthException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            aResponse.sendRedirect(MY_AS_URL + "?redirect_uri=localhost:9001/home");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's what I am looking, but right now the problem I have is the redirect to AS. I can't get that to work. Ill add my RS code, maybe someone can assist with that

Comment: @Jan Here you go -- hope that helps

Comment: looks good and does what it's suppoesed, but i need to look into why the url after logging in doesn't redirect me to localhost:9000/home eventhough it has it in the url. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Beware of your redirects: sometimes, you end up redirecting to something like `localhost:9001/localhost:9000/home` or such. Good luck ^^ It was nice to see a well-formatted, researched question for once.

Comment: Hi @Nathan and Jan : Do you have a demo of it?

Comment: @James Hi, I do have a small version of it (buggy though), but I can't relly share it as it's workplace code. But you can try to take an example from OAuth or Spring security websites and work around them. If you have any question, don't hesitate to ask (you can tag me in your question comments or link it to me)

Comment: @Nathan: Thanks for getting back to me. I fix that issue but now, I want to send authorisation code in response and want to generate access token based on that. Can you guide me on that? Or do you have any article to do that implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the Spring framework, but hopefully this helps anyways:

OAuth is an **authorization protocol**. It does not handle **authentication** (see also: "[What is the difference between authentication and authorization?](https://serverfault.com/questions/57077/what-is-the-difference-between-authentication-and-authorization)" on ServerFault).

If I understand you correctly, you want users to be redirected to `/login` when they go to `/home` and aren't already logged-in. This step has nothing to do with OAuth, it must be part of your application's security / firewall setup.

Please also note that there is a difference between logging in (authenticating) on the authorization server and actually granting the application the right to access your resources (authorization). First you have to prove who you are and only then can you give access to your stuff. These are two separate steps.